# Which is faster, imagemagick class or exec()

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am currently using php exec() to generate the image by imagemagick because I can't use the imagick class because I got this

```
Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found
```

As a solution, I use the exec(), but the problem is, the execution is too slow.

I haven't tried to use the imagick class so I don't have an idea if generating in this way is more faster than the exec().

The question is, which is better to use, imagick class or exec()?

UPDATE:
this is my phpinfo GD
[image]

and here is the version of imagick that I have

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.0.7 08/25/10 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2004 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

Comment: Could you paste the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`?

Comment: is it safe to show my phpinfo? at what part you need to see? that's too big to print screen.

Comment: The whole detail is not needed - adamdunson is probably looking for anything that mentions imagick or gd

Comment: @adamdunson I updated my question, I uploaded the copy of my phpinfo GD

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally, exec should be disabled on your server for security - if its not your server.. well - it still should be :-)

I have never seen it disabled on any server I have used; shared or not.

> Safe_mode Removed from PHP, and generates a fatal E_CORE_ERROR level error when enabled.

Anyway its horses for courses - in some cases Imagick is faster; in others GD is faster it just depends on what you are trying to do. But Imagemagick is probably slower than IMagick.

I did some speed test a couple of years ago with some interesting results: [Results PDF](http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/speed/Speed_tests_1.pdf) and they could probably do with updating now.

On larger files GD hung but there may be ways to increase the memory. Imagick is more confusing to use if you are doing something a bit more complicated.

As you do not say what you are doing I can not offer any more information.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Imagick class is faster.

Reason: Exec has to fork a new process to load the convert executable (or whichever tool of imagemagick you are using).. so generally the first time it will have to go to disk to find the binary.. future attempts should use the OS cache to load it so would be comparable in speed

The imagick class is a linked library compiled into PHP that *should* offer better performance depending on how php is loaded in your system (CGI / fastcgi / extension)

As another poster has said, the imagick class has less options - however in my experience in 99% of cases where the options wasn't directly available, there is another way to do it.

Edit: Ideally, exec should be disabled on your server for security - if its not your server.. well - it still should be :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, they're both comparable in terms of speed. The big downside, is lack of options and customization when it comes to the Imagick classes. That said, I usually avoid exec() for the security implications though.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the imagick class as exec is a security issue. However, it isn't really needed in the first place. Try using the [built-in GD functions.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)